# Data Analysis in Matlab over Emoji usage on iMessage

Tags: regex, matlab, utf-8, emoji

I found a service that will read my messages into a CSV, however I am not sure which encoding to use. I want to be able to perform regular expressions over emojis, but can't figure out how to read in a UTF-8 encoding in such a way that I can search for corresponding UTF-8 values for emojis given online.

Answer (score 0):

You can fread the file, convert it using Matlab's native2unicode() function (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/native2unicode.html) and search it using unicode.